# jQuery $.get loading relative data but not executing the callback

Tags: jquery, jquery-callback

The following doesn't come across as a cross-domain issue, but it smells like one.

So here's my setup (that's quickly making me grey):

I have an index.html file that is loading a flat file called config.json that resides right next to index.html. I have used both $(document).ready() and window.addEventListener('load'... to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get('config.json', function(data){
        alert('asd');
    })
});
```

The alert *almost* never fires. This happens in Chrome 9 and Firefox 3.6 and FF4. Haven't tried other browsers. I look in Firebug and the dev console under the network tab and I can see config.json loading. It has the proper headers (application/json). So the data is getting loaded, but the callback function doesn't fire.

However, in Firefox if I refresh in a quick-double pattern (like a heartbeat), then very occasionally my alert fires. I can only get Firefox to do that in 3.6, so I'm assuming its because the js engine is a bit slower than v4 and Chrome.

To top it off, it gets stranger. If I set a full path to config.json on the same domain, it fails to load. If I set config.path to http://localhost/config.json and access the site from http://local.mac.com/ my alert FIRES! If I switch the domains and access from localhost and use http://local.mac.com (or abcdef.com) for config.json, it ALSO FIRES.

I have a domain of "local.mac.com" setup in /etc/hosts (mac) so I can test sites with that instead of localhost. I also tried another domain in /etc/hosts of "abcdef.com" and get the same results.

There *must* be something that I'm just missing because its almost 2am my time, but I'm flummoxed. Can someone tell me what the hell is going on?

Comment: $.get('config.json', {}, function(data) {});

Comment: Have you tried using the $.ajax method using the JSON dataType? Like this: $.ajax({ url: 'config.json', dataType: 'json', data: {}, success: function(data){ alert('asd'); } });

Comment: @Wayne, you should put that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try the $.getJSON call ??

```
$.getJSON('config.json', null, function(data) { alert(data);  });
```